# What can I do to get my car to stop surging?

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, surging

2001 Chevy Malibu has been surging for the past 2 years. The transmission has been checked, I had just replaced the catalitic converter around the same time the car started surging. I took off the MAF and the car stopped surging but it rode rough. I replaced the MAF and the car still surges. It starts to surge after a right turn, after it goes over a speed bump, after it goes over a dip. It surges going up hill, it starts to surge when the car comes to a sudden stop or after I slam on the brakes. And now it even starts to surge when I'm just driving straight down the road and I excelerate. I put the OBD2 machine on it but it does not have any codes(DTC'S) on it. Please help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Check your motor mounts. I'm not sure about your car, but would assume it is drive by cable. If so, the engine could be tilting when doing any of these actions, pulling slightly on the cable, which could cause the surge.

Comment: Most Surges are due to IACV valve either clogged or bad. If that is not the case check fuel pressure as it may go up and down.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Chevy van do that same thing and after several pricey mechanics looked at it a "good ole local boy" mechanic found the issue. My main computer was mounted under my drivers seat and was loose. Going around corners, up hills, stopping ect.... Would break connection and cause surging that drove me crazy for months! He bolted it back down and fixed several wires that we're loose from all the movement. Problem solved!